# Is there a simple regex to compare numbers to x?

Tags: regex

I want a regex that will match if a number is greater than or equal to an arbitrary number.  This seems monstrously complex for such a simple task... it seems like you need to reinvent 'counting' in an explicit regex hand-crafted for the x.

For example, intuitively to do this for numbers greater than 25, I get

```
(\d{3,}|[3-9]\d|2[6-9]\d)
```

What if the number was 512345?  Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `x > 25`? What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to do this with a regular expression? Why not accept any number and in a later stage reject the ones you don't like?

Comment: In regex you usually need only one `|`, what flavor are you using?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas There are some frameworks which don't allow for this. Things like masks for jquery. But you can obviously do it later.

Comment: +1 (offsetting) Why the downvote? We're in agreement that a regex is an inappropriate way to compare integers. Just because a question can't be answered as stated doesn't make it a bad question. I see this as an opportunity for the OP, as well as subsequent StackOverflow visitors to learn from this post.

Comment: @Philipee I need this because it's used as input to a more complex (third party) log scanning utility which takes actions when certain lines show up in logs I'm monitoring.  The only thing it accepts is an exact match string or a regex, so I'm stuck.  I'm considering writing a perl module which takes a range and generates the (possibly 100s of chars) appropriate regex.

Comment: @yuri Fixed, I don't write regexes often and java syntax came naturally to my fingers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that there is no simpler way. regex is not thing that for numbers.
You may try this one:

```
\[1-9]d{6,}|
[6-9]\d{5}|
5[2-9]\d{4}|
51[3-9]\d{3}|
512[4-9]\d{2}|
5123[5-9]\d|
51234[6-9]
```

(newlines for clarity)

Comment: That first alternative should be `[1-9]\d{6,}`, not `\d{7,}`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

> What if the number was 512345? Is there a simpler way?

No, a regex to match a number in a certain range will be a horrible looking thing (especially large numbers ranges).

Regex is simply not meant for such tasks. The better solution would be to "freely" match the digits, like `\d+`, and then compare them with the language's relational operators (`<`, `>`, ...).

Answer (score 2):

In Perl you can use the conditional regexp construct `(?(condition)yes-pattern)` where the `(condition)` is `(?{CODE})` to run arbitrary Perl code.  If you make the `yes-pattern` be `(*FAIL)` then you have a regexp fragment which succeeds only when `CODE` returns false.  Thus:

```
foreach (0 .. 50) {
    if (/\A(\d+)(?(?{$1 <= 25})(*FAIL))\z/) {
        say "$_ matches";
    }
    else {
        say "$_ does not match";
    }
}
```

The code-evaluation feature used to be marked as experimental but the latest 'perlre' manual page (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) seems to now imply it is a core language feature.

Technically, what you have is no longer a 'regular expression' of course, but some hybrid of regexp and external code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a regex flavor that can do that.  Writing a Perl module to generate the appropriate regex (as you mentioned in your comment) sounds like a good idea to me.  In fact, I'd be surprised if it hasn't been done already.  Check CPAN first.

By the way, your regex contains a few more errors besides the excess pipes [Yuriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133910/yuriy-faktorovich) pointed out.

- First, the "three or more digits" portion will match invalid numbers like `024` and `00000007`.  You can solve that by requiring the first digit to be greater than zero.  If you want to allow for leading zeroes, you can match them separately.
- The third part, `2[6-9]\d`, only matches numbers >= 260.  Perhaps you meant to make the third digit optional (i.e. `2[6-9]\d?`), but that would be redundant.
- You should anchor the regex somehow to make sure you aren't matching part of a longer number or a "word" with digits in it.  I don't know the best way to do that in your particular situation, but word boundaries (i.e. `\b`) will probably be all you need.

End result:

```
\b0*([1-9]\d{2,}|[3-9]\d|2[6-9])\b
```