# How would i write regex for 250 or more?

Tags: regex

Been stuck on this for a while now. How would I write regular expression to match 250 and all numbers greater than 250?
By that I mean lets say I want to match all tickets that cost £250 or more.

Comment: which regex syntax do you use? (language?) why do you need a regex?

Comment: Are you sure a regex is the right tool for this?

Comment: I am revising for a exam this is past exam question. I been looking at the quantifiers but not sure how to match it to the value 150 or more. I know how to match it to 150 times or more but not to specific value.

Comment: If you've been *stuck on it for a while*, is there a reason you haven't included at least a single effort you've made yourself?

Comment: After solving the problem, I would have included a @Ismail's sentiment that Regex is not the appropriate tool to solve this problem.  Offering insight into what tools and technologies are appropriate for the problems you face is what will make you successful in the real world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it doesn't make sense to use Regexp for numeric comparisons, here's a way to do it:

First, lets see what all numbers greater than 250 have in common:

Case 1: 250 <= x <= 299

- 3 digits
- `2` is the first digit
- Second digit is between `5` and `9`
- Third digit is between `0` and `9`

The regular expression to match this would be:
`/2[5-9][0-9]/`

Case 2: 300 <= x <= 999

- Number of digits is 3
- First digit between `3` and `9`
- All other digits between `0` and `9`

The regular expression for this would be:
`/[3-9][0-9]{2}/`

Case 3: x >= 1000

- 4 or more digits
- First digit is non-zero

The regexp here is:
`/[1-9][0-9]{3,}/`

Joining these with an `OR` condition, you get the full regexp as:

`/£(2[5-9][0-9]|[3-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3,})/`

Of course, a much simpler way would be to just pull out the number, and then compare the `$1` capturing group in a programming language like so:

`/£(\d{1,})/`

**EDIT**: To include decimals, append `\.[0-9]{0,2}` to allow matches to `£999`, `£999.5` and `£999.99`.

However, keep in mind that this isn't really needed if you just want to check if the number is greater, because the original RegExp will return true for cases like `£999.99` too, even though it will just match the integer part.

Comment: Thanks, i really didnt think about splitting it up. also if I was going to add pennies at the end, it would be just \.[0-9]{2}

Comment: However, I'd suggest using `\.[0-9]{0,2}` to include the possibility of someone specifying the number as £250.5 or just £250

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to identify the numeric value in the text and then parse and compare to perform any value-based logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python-style regex that will probably do what you want it to do:

```
\d{4,}|[3456789]\d{2}|2[56789]\d
```

It matches all digit strings 4 characters in length or more, as well as those 3 characters in length that begin with a number greater than 2, as well as those 3 characters in length that begin with a 2 and have a second character greater than 4.

This will only match positive integers correctly.

Comment: Careful, the first part will match numbers with leading `0`s.

Answer (score 0):

Tailor it to your regex engine:

```
([1-9][0-9]{3,}|[3-9][0-9]{2}|2[5-9][0-9])
```

Comment: okay, so you are trying to match 250 or more by the first part, then 300-999 in the second and above 1000 or more. thanks I did not think to divide it up.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible, Regex is not really designed to easily compare numbers as discussed here: [Is there a simple regex to compare numbers to x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8620112/910348)

Regex can be used to parse out the number like this:

```
£(\d+)
```

Then you can compare the number found ($1) against the limits.