# Redirect with nginx for all id less than a fixed value, how?

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, devops

In nginx config file need to redirect all articles with $id less than a fixed value. $ID - i am getting from the query string. But nginx does not support comparison operators "<", ">".
What to do ? How to solve the problem?
Redirect through php - not the best solution ....

Comment: maybe you can use nginScript for this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/nginScript/

Comment: Yes , may be. But experemental module.

Comment: It will not be pretty, but you could concoct a regular expression. What is the fixed value and the minimum and maximum values?

Comment: Yes , now i try it ) But not finished.
Here already regexp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620112/is-there-a-simple-regex-to-compare-numbers-to-x

Answer (score 1):

If the value you try to compare is not too fancy you can still use regex:

```
^(\d){1,3}$
```

This would Match from 0 to 999.
You raise the 3 to a 5 it goes from 0 to 99999 and so on.

Comment: Thenk you.I'm about and solved this problem.
My answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:
**Redirect** pages on certain rules, with the **exception** of some specific

```
#### 
# In http section 
# It is expetion pages
###
#set $stayHere 0;
    map $request_uri $stayHere {
        include snippets/pages.map;
    }

#### 
# End http section 
###
```

---

```
#### 
# File pages.map
###
~\/expetionPage.+ A;
~\/expetionPage2.+ A;
~\/expetionPage995Test.+ A;
#### 
# End File pages.map
###
```

---

```
####
# In server section
####
set $oldPage 0;
## Redirect For pages less 45329 in the rquest
## If it is not exeption page

    if ($request_uri !~ "([1-9]\d{5,}|[5-9]\d{4}|4[6-9]\d{3}|45[4-9]\d{2}|453[3-9]\d{1}|45329)"){
        set $oldPage "${stayHere}A";
    }

#####
# some conditions
#####
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/$) {
        set $oldPage "AA";
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ "\/[a-zA-Z\-\/]+") {
        set $oldPage "AA";
    }
#####
#redirect if for my rule, if not exeption
#####
if ($oldPPage = "A"){
    return 301 http://newPage.net$request_uri;
}
```