# validate page ranges for printing regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need Regular Expression that validates the page ranges.
(Eg. Print custom pages)

Currently, I have tried this expression

```
/^(?!([ \d]*-){2})\d+(?: *[-,] *\d+)*$/
```

It should accept values like

```
 1, 3, 6-9
 1-5, 5
 6, 9
```

It should not accept values like

```
 ,5
 5-,9
 9-5,
 2,6-
 10-1
```

Comment: You can't do that with regex only. Split on commas, check if each item matches `/^\d+(?:-\d+)?$/` regex and if yes and the item has `-`, split with `-` and make sure the first number is less than the second number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you can, just will have to repeat yourself once (feels against DRY principle but welp)

Comment: @MichałKrzysztofFeiler What do you mean?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew like, `/^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,\s*)*\d+(?:-\d+)?\s*$/`

Comment: It will match `56-0` range that is invalid. In a regex, you cannot compare captured numeric values

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh you're right

Comment: you're right! @WiktorStribiżew 

Check this out. https://regex101.com/r/lS8vP9/29
5-1 is being matched

Comment: heh perl has nice things that would enable us to use just regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/30936388/4240261

Comment: it will be easier to split on `,` than to use `matchAll`. not necessarily so for `-` tho, for them regex `.match` is good.

Comment: With Javascript replace you could [pass a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for verifying ranges and just remove all valid tokens. If string is empty it should be fine. [See this demo](https://tio.run/##ZU/RTsMwDHzPVxx7WJKRbKNISKOU/cgkVFJ3FLqkSlMkVPXbiwtCSPBgW3enO9uv5XvZu9h0yfpQ0TzXg3epCR7uhdzbU5@i4tJiFECkNEQPxttIXVs6Ujt1qq41Nup4b7l/A31kaJZ5et6dDdRlb3C54co0ikcsWUBTQ6WPjkLNPK6KAnLwFdWNp0pivV7Yh4J9GuMEanvC@HPCapVj4pSJ8xajzMUkhAu@Dy1t23BWLP5@IHn3rcGdPUht/ih7y2L2n7fZFy10Ps@f).

Comment: @bobblebubble Your demo is quite good ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At that point I wont bother with a regex hard to read by a neophyte. A regex-free, but verbose, solution with pure js:

- We split by comma
- We trim all trailing whitespaces
- We check if each part are valid
- We return false when a falsy range is found

Demo:

```
const isNumeric = input => !isNaN(input) // you may also check if the value is a nonzero positive integer
const isOrdered = (start, end) => parseInt(start) < parseInt(end)
const isRangeValid = range => range.length == 2 && range.every(isNumeric) && isOrdered(range[0], range[1])
const isSingleValid = single => single.length == 1 && isNumeric(single[0])

function f(input) {
    const inputs = input.split(',').map(x => x.trim());

    for (const x of inputs) {
        if (!x) return false;
        const pages = x.split('-');
        if (!isSingleValid(pages) && !isRangeValid(pages))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(f("1, 3, 6-9"))
console.log(f("1-5, 5"))
console.log(f("6, 9"))

console.log(f(",5"))
console.log(f("5-,9"))
console.log(f("9-5,"))
console.log(f("2,6-"))
console.log(f("10-1"))
console.log(f("56-0"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHNTuswEIXX8VNMWVBbckrLVSuhUvZsQAKJDerCSiep703syHaiFMSzF9tpys/NznNm5nz28V/RCpsZWbtU6R0ej5lW1oG0D02FRmawAanqxsHmDiZeFQ801gyuruCgG6jEAURpNWR7zP6BzMHtEVpRNuhdQIDS6g2Nhlpb6WTrVeWwQEMG0qPZocGdJ1HrhHEcUO1YANbCWLxXrtcZ3H4pYeTs8CRUgS@ilMHEhCJsx8OsRFW4PWw2cA2XlycRWzQHKh1WYfD82KgwFubO16Jx43W@5f3u62L7BX6WqijPZBur4NifvrEXvefA6fuMkLxRmZNaQT7E@k6Sk3uo7ZD/zNaldHTKp2xWiZp2AdPNnJEVZWxNSJJrA7QVBjrQ@Wk72iX@T@ikY2DQNcaj/Hfh2us9pxYFBkw3INIpWw9bP55I42iMZ/I99JPO/FLyi/FBEjJozjReIh8kxqdDPrqgOb1YcPjDYZXeXDD2Xy9dcliONFYc4vxvnY8NL1M@Zn7jzUfka75Kx64yTxdj3qt07uXj8RM)

Comment: Feel free to comment if I have any failing testcases