# Regular expression for 'number x' greater than 'number y'

Tags: regex

Working with image sizes, I need a regular expression which returns sizes (of images) which their height is greater than their width.
The sizes are (for example) 300x200, 300x100, 300x400. In this case only the last one (300*400) would match.

I've tried a simplified version which only checks the first digit is greater, like this:

```
/(\d)[0-9]+x[$1-9][0-9]+/
```

But it didn't work. How can I do that?

thanks,
Dan

Comment: Nope, regular expressions are for pattern matching and replacement, not logic (i.e. greater than/less than).  You'll need to extract the height and width, then, using the language of your choice, compare the two.

Comment: Are you just dealing with numbers like 100 and 200 and ... what about `289*810`?

Comment: I need to match all, but even a simplified version which matches only compares the first digit will do

Comment: @Mr.Llama 
thanks, didnt knew that. write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Dani, what is the regex flavor? It is possible with at least .NET regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general case, you cannot use a regex to compare captured numbers within a single regex match operation. You need to cast the captured value to a number first and then compare, and if the result is as expected, put the found value(s) to the resulting array/list.

If you are using .NET regex, you still can get your necessary matches with a pure regex solution. Here is a bit modified regex described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32608090/3832970) by [@Sebastian Schumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2729609/sebastian-schumann):

```cs
\b(?:
  0+x0*[1-9]\d*
  |
  (?:(?>0*)(?<length>\d)+x(?>0*)(?<-length>\d)*(?(length)(?!))\d+
  |   
  (
   (?=(?>0*)(?<o>\d)+x(?>0*)(?<-o>\d)*(?(o)(?!))\b)
   (?>0*)
   (?<prefix>\d*)
   (?:(?<g0>0)|(?<g1>1)|(?<g2>2)|(?<g3>3)|(?<g4>4)|(?<g5>5)|(?<g6>6)|(?<g7>7)|(?<g8>8)|(?<g9>9))
   \d*
 x
   (?>0*)
   \k<prefix>
   (?(g0)[1-9]|(?(g1)[2-9]|(?(g2)[3-9]|(?(g3)[4-9]|(?(g4)[5-9]|(?(g5)[6-9]|(?(g6)[7-9]|(?(g7)[89]|(?(g8)9|(?!))))))))))
   \d*
  )
 )
)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3a%0d%0a++0%2bx0*%5b1-9%5d%5cd*%0d%0a++%7c%0d%0a++%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3e0*%29%28%3f%3clength%3e%5cd%29%2bx%28%3f%3e0*%29%28%3f%3c-length%3e%5cd%29*%28%3f%28length%29%28%3f!%29%29%5cd%2b%5cb%0d%0a++%7c+++%0d%0a++%28%0d%0a+++%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3e0*%29%28%3f%3co%3e%5cd%29%2bx%28%3f%3e0*%29%28%3f%3c-o%3e%5cd%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%5cb%29%0d%0a+++%28%3f%3e0*%29%0d%0a+++%28%3f%3cprefix%3e%5cd*%29%0d%0a+++%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cg0%3e0%29%7c%28%3f%3cg1%3e1%29%7c%28%3f%3cg2%3e2%29%7c%28%3f%3cg3%3e3%29%7c%28%3f%3cg4%3e4%29%7c%28%3f%3cg5%3e5%29%7c%28%3f%3cg6%3e6%29%7c%28%3f%3cg7%3e7%29%7c%28%3f%3cg8%3e8%29%7c%28%3f%3cg9%3e9%29%29%0d%0a+++%5cd*%0d%0a+x%0d%0a+++%28%3f%3e0*%29%0d%0a+++%5ck%3cprefix%3e%0d%0a+++%28%3f%28g0%29%5b1-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g1%29%5b2-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g2%29%5b3-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g3%29%5b4-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g4%29%5b5-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g5%29%5b6-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g6%29%5b7-9%5d%7c%28%3f%28g7%29%5b89%5d%7c%28%3f%28g8%299%7c%28%3f!%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%0d%0a+++%5cd*%0d%0a++%29%0d%0a+%29%0d%0a%29%5cb&i=1x2+22x10+1x23+23x23+2x2+300x200+300x100+300x400+0x0&o=xm). I removed the part that matched `x=y` cases (with `x` = `0`) and replaced anchors with word boundaries to find matches inside longer strings.

If you can use Perl, you can use [this modified solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30936541/3832970) originally written by [@Ed Avis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626804/ed-avis):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$s = "1x2 22x10 1x23 23x23  300x200 300x100 300x400";
my @matches;
while ($s =~ /\b(\d+)x(\d+)\b(?(?{$1 >= $2})(*FAIL))/g) {
  push(@matches, $&);
}
say "@matches";
# 1x2 1x23 300x400
```

See an [online Perl demo](https://ideone.com/sXDhvY). Here, I replaced anchors with word boundaries and this code snippet fetches all matches found in some string. This regex matches like this:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more digits
- `x` - a `x` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?(?{$1 >= $2})(*FAIL))` - an insert executing Perl code: if Group 1 value is greater than or equal to Group 2 value, the match is failed (`(*FAIL)` verb returns false and the next match is being searched for, it is equal to `(?!)`).