# Regex Pattern number1 to number2

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm searching for a pattern for the following behavior:

```
number1-number2
number1: Can be everything >= 0 and <= int.MaxValue
number2: Can be everything >= number1 and <= int.MaxValue
```

e.g.

```
"1-2" => True
"0-0" => True
"10-22" => True
"22-10" => False
"10-10" => True
"a-b" => False
```

It would be also nice if I could directly extract the two int values.

Comment: No, This won't be possible through regex..

Comment: @PranavCBalan then why he says `"22-10" => False ` ? see the order.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : oh missed that.... :)

Comment: why you won't just _split_ and _if_? methinks you can't check this condition `number2: Can be everything >= number1 and <= int.MaxValue` with regex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expressions: Matching if number is greater then...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640192/regular-expressions-matching-if-number-is-greater-then)

Comment: Can you have negative "numbers" in the range? Just will there be more than 1 "-"?

Comment: Regular expressions are for *pattern matching*, what you are trying to do is a *logic test*, this is not what regex is for and won't be possible without additional code.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It is possible but not recommended. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a regex for comparing extracted numbers. You need to parse the values with `int.TryParse` and implement other checks to get what you need.

Assuming you only have ***integer positive numbers*** in the ranges, here is a `String.Split` and `int.TryParse` approach:

```
private bool CheckMyRange(string number_range, ref int n1, ref int n2)
{
    var rng = number_range.Split('-');
    if (rng.GetLength(0) != 2) 
       return false;

    if (!int.TryParse(rng[0], out n1))
       return false;
    if (!int.TryParse(rng[1], out n2))
       return false;
    if (n1 >= 0 && n1 <= int.MaxValue)
       if (n2 >= n1 && n2 <= int.MaxValue)
           return true;
    return false;
}
```

And call it like

```
int n1 = -1;
int n2 = -1;
bool result = CheckMyRange("1-2", ref n1, ref n2);
```

Comment: _You cannot use a regex for comparing extracted numbers._ Thats not correkt. It is possible.

Comment: @Verarind: Let OP and others decide  what is correct for this concrete task. I believe regex is not appropriate here.

Comment: Yes I'm with you that regex is not appropriate in that case. Using your code will be much faster - but it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

It is possible to test it using regex - but you should prefer a solution in code because it will be much faster. This regex needs a lot of backtracking. The only advantage of this regex is that it works for an arbitrary number length.

```
(?:^0+-\d+$)
|
(?:^(?>0*)(?<number>\d+)-(?>0*)\k<number>$)
|
(?:
    (?:^(?>0*)(?<length>\d)+-(?>0*)(?<-length>\d)*(?(length)(?!))\d+$)
    |
    (
        (?=^(?>0*)(?<o>\d)+-(?>0*)(?<-o>\d)*(?(o)(?!))$)
        ^
            (?>0*)
            (?<prefix>\d*)
            (?:(?<g0>0)|(?<g1>1)|(?<g2>2)|(?<g3>3)|(?<g4>4)|(?<g5>5)|(?<g6>6)|(?<g7>7)|(?<g8>8)|(?<g9>9))
            \d*
        -
            (?>0*)
            \k<prefix>
            (?(g0)[1-9]|(?(g1)[2-9]|(?(g2)[3-9]|(?(g3)[4-9]|(?(g4)[5-9]|(?(g5)[6-9]|(?(g6)[7-9]|(?(g7)[89]|(?(g8)9|(?!))))))))))
            \d*
        $
    )
)
```

This matches for every `x-y` where `x <= y` for positive integer numbers including leeding zeros.

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/PlURfP)

It doesn't work for chars.

**Explanation**

I was able to create a regex that matches `x-y` for all `x < y`. The question was `x <= y`. So I splitted the question to `x = y | x < y`.

We need to handle that the first or both numbers does only contain zeros but that's trivial:

```
^0+-\d+$
```

Now the case *`x = y`*

```
^(?>0*)(?<number>\d+)-(?>0*)\k<number>$
```

The tricky part is `x < y`.

1. `x` is smaller than `y` if `x` is shorter in char length than `y` (leeding zeros are captured by an atomic group):

   `^(?>0*)(?<length>\d)+-(?>0*)(?<-length>\d)*(?(length)(?!))\d+`

   This first group captures the whole number by one capture per digit. After the separator a balancing group definition clears the capture stack and forces at least one more digit.
2. Both numbers are of the same length (if the first number is longer it is also greater and should not match).

   To ensure that both numbers are of the same length I started with a positive look behind assertion that ensures it the same way I tested for a longer number in step 1:

   `(?=^(?>0*)(?<o>\d)+-(?>0*)(?<-o>\d)*(?(o)(?!))$)`

   After that the algorithm is simple. Start at the beginning. If the current digit is equal go to the next digit. If the current `x`-digit is slower than the current `y`-digit we're finished and a match is found. If it's slower we should not match. This is done by that pattern:

   ```
   ^
       (?>0*)   # cut out leeding zeros
       (?<prefix>\d*)
       .*
   -
       (?>0*)   # cut out leeding zeros
       \k<prefix>  # both numbers start with the same part
       .*
   $
   ```

   And now the check for one digit. There are only 10 possibilities [0-9]. Each of them is captures by a single group:

   `(?<g0>0)|(?<g1>1)|(?<g2>2)|(?<g3>3)|(?<g4>4)|(?<g5>5)|(?<g6>6)|(?<g7>7)|(?<g8>8)|(?<g9>9)`

   Now we're able to use conditions to check whether the current `y`-digit is greater then the current `x`-digit. Lets show for 0 and 1:

   `(?<g0>0)|(?<g1>1)`: If a 0 matches for the current `x`-digit there are only `[1-9]` for the current `y`-digit. If 1 matches only `[2-9]` is able. This could be used in a condition:

   `(?(g0)[1-9]|...)` what means if `g0` has a capture `[1-9]` has to match otherwise the rest has to match. This is combined to:

   `(?(g0)[1-9]|(?(g1)[2-9]|(?(g2)[3-9]|(?(g3)[4-9]|(?(g4)[5-9]|(?(g5)[6-9]|(?(g6)[7-9]|(?(g7)[89]|(?(g8)9|(?!))))))))))`

   The last trick is that none of the groups `g[0-8]` has been matched only `g9` is available and there is no greater digit possible and the match should fail `(?!)`.

This all has been combined to the whole regex that matches `x-y` for all `x <= y`.

Comment: Explaining what you did there will be useful.

Comment: I think `12346-12345`  must be `False`, but your regex [matches it](http://goo.gl/9tCMYq).

Comment: @Verarind: Please do not put more effort into it, or if you do, please let us know how long it took you. I wrote my code in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: @stribizhev Okay. I don't know how long it took because I wrote it long time ago for matching `x < y`. I thought that adapting to `x <= y` would be easy but it meight wrong.

Comment: @stribizhev I changed my answer. It took me about 40mins to create it (and 25min to create the explanation because I'm not a native speaker).

Comment: Regardless of how long it took, you actually answered the question in a neat (but purely academic) way. Thanks for sharing this monster.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a web service that could run this regex?

Comment: @Hoten I added a link.

Answer (score 1):

Regex can only be used to match the numbers. Post that a comparison operation needs to be done.

```
string num="number1-number2";//where (number1 & number2)=numeric val
MatchCollection stringVal= Regex.Matches(num,@"\d+");
int num1=Convert.ToInt32(stringVal[0].Value);
int num2=Convert.ToInt32(stringVal[1].Value);
if(num1>=0 && num1<=int.MaxValue && num2>=num1 && num2<=int.MaxValue)
    return true;
else
   return false;
```

will give you an array containing the the numbers

Comment: well using regex we cannot perform comparison, all we can do is match and extract the data. so once the data is available the comparison operation should be taken care of seperately

Comment: in your sample `num1` always same as `num2` :-D